# ImageField not showing in CCK under Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I'm running Drupal 6.12 and I've installed the CCK, ImageField, FileField and ImageCache modules.  I've create a new content type called 'Photo' and then click on 'Manage Fields', so that I can add an ImageField to this content type.

When I do this, ImageField isn't in the drop-down list.  I've searched around and other people don't seem to be having this issue, so clearly I must be doing something wrong.  I even created a new test site and installed just those modules from scratch, but I still get the same behaviour.

Have you had this?  If so, I'd be really grateful to learn how you fixed it.  I want to make a gallery of image nodes in Drupal and I thought this would be the perfect way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first select "**file**" under the *Type of data to store* and then from the subsequent dropdown (a little to the right) you will be able to select "**image**" under *Form element to edit the data*.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks very much.  If only the book could've told me that!

Answer (score 0):

ImageField uses a different API for Drupal 6, it is now based on FileField module (previously was Image API). So ImageField is now widget of FileField, which makes more sense.